# How good is to use Elasitc search Prefix query with respect to performance?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I am planning to maintain search history of users by indexing each search text as a document in elastic search. I thought of using a Prefix query to get list of Suggestions for the users. along with the prefix query i have used an Multimatch query to get the terms that match in the middle of the text as well.

the pseudo query looks like below :

```
{
"query" : {
    bool : {
          should : {
                    "Prefix query"{
                      }
                     "multimatch query"{
                     }
            } 
    }
}
```

}

Before that I would like to know how good is it use Prefix Query for sugestions.

I am maintaining an Index for each day and would like to query the history of last 30 days.

will it be an performance issue ? want to clear this before I start implementing it.and are there any alternative's for prefix query in this kind of a scenario.

**I have already implemented suggestions with Completion suggester**
but my requirement is to provide user with suggestions based on history and with a support of **matching the terms in the middle of the text** as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous project we used the query language, which heavily rely on operators like this **star**|*part-of-term*|**star**, and I could say in some bad curcimstances (big index - 100+ mln docs, big text to analyze, complex terms, multiple languages) - Lucene could behave slowly (basically, because leading stars are heavy in standard Lucene implementation, also, they are prohibited). All it was implemented without **MultiMatchQuery**.

One could imagine, that implementing improvements like suffix arrays (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) will help (at least it helped us)

So, conclusion, be careful, and if your index (since it's only 30 days of history) is relatively small you should be fine.

Comment: this would really boost me to start. thanks for the experience

Answer (score 0):

Usually Elasticsearch does a good job in search. It could be slower in complex nested aggregation queries but simple search is very fast. I don't think you need to worry too much in advance.